Outlet randomly losing power
An outlet in our house is currently feeding the cable modem, wifi router, and an LED lamp, via a surge protector strip. The other half of the duplex isn't being used.
For a long time now, this outlet will "lose" power at random times, causing the devices plugged in to cycle. The blip is momentary (as in, the devices will regain power immediately) and doesn't seem correlated with large loads running elsewhere (furnace, dehumidifier,...). The timing of the surges is erratic; they have happened up to once or twice per day, but usually there are a few days between occurrences.
I have replaced the power strip with a higher rated surge protector, but it hasn't helped (there is no whole-house surge protection). Both halves of that outlet have the same issue. We don't really use the other outlets on that circuit, so I can't say if those are also problematic. The circuit is an MWBC, if it matters.
Does anyone have any ideas what might be the issue? I remember having a look at the wiring a year or two ago, but I don't think I saw anything that jumped out at me. I'm happy enough to replace the outlet on the off chance that it's something internal, but I'm not even sure that would do any good.

It does sound like a loose connection.  If the plug needs some force to put in or take out, then the wires on the receptacle might be loose.  If the plug goes in very easy, then replace the receptacle.  Turn off the breaker before working on it.

Sounds like a good answer @crip659 !

LED can do that. Unplug it to test

What does "The other half of the duplex isn't in use" exactly mean? There can be something parasitic left running in an empty apartment causing this. There can also be a loose (part of the) cable that's exposed to something mechanical or climatic (I have a fire alarm that would go off in two different weeks of the year, only if a late evening low spring/autumn sun on an extra-clear day JUST SO threw rays between a door and a wardrobe.

turn off the breaker that runs the circuit feeding this outlet
identify all other outlets/switches on that circuit... specifically anything upstream of this receptacle to the breaker.
there's a loose connection somewhere, not necessarily the wire connections at this receptacle but start with these connections first.
somewhat easy/effective way is put a incandescent light on this outlet, go around kicking other wall outlets (without breaking them) and cycling switches and see which one causes the light to flicker.
its not a MWBC overloaded neutral issue.
